# How to graph my information?

Tags: plotting

I'm unsure if this is the correct space to post this question however it seems the most suitable.

I have some information that I'm trying to represent in a graph or some sort of visual representation.

It's the distance that the sensor can detect ( range from 0-300cm) at each 10 degree incrementation ( 0-90 degrees). I looked at polar plot as an option however I didn't entirely understand how to configure one.

What would be the best way to represent this sort of information?

Comment: Is this related to the software [Wolfram Mathematica](http://wri.com) in any way?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407351/87876). You need to edit some unnecessary parts.

Answer (score 1):

First, some data to work with:

```
list1 = Table[{t  Degree, N[Sin[t Degree]]}, {t, 0, 90, 5}]
```

then, perhaps the following is of use to you

```
ListPolarPlot[list1, Joined -> True]
```

And if this doesn't help, give us a little data to work on and your own efforts at solving the problem to work from.